# VBA Loop function for n number of times

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a macro which counts blank values in my selection and then uses that count in order to loop a macro to insert new sheets "mycount" number of times. How do I do the second, loop part? Thank you

```
     'cnt blank cells in col U
     Dim mycount As Long
     mycount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection)


    ‘add sheets for number of mycount
    Dim looper as integer
    Looper=mycount
    Do while looper <=mycount
    Sheets.add after:=ActiveSheet
    Loop
```

Comment: There are several variations in [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures#t=201608231550302751355).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go to infinite loop. You need to increment your control variable

```
Do while looper <=mycount
    Sheets.add after:=ActiveSheet
    looper=looper +1
 Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a `For Loop`.

```
Dim mycount As Long
Dim i       as Long
mycount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection)

'This will add 'MyCount' number of sheets
for i = 1 to myCount
    Sheets.add after:=ActiveSheet
Next i`
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add new sheets `mycount` number of times:

```
Sub Test()
Dim mycount As Long
    mycount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection)
For i = 1 To mycount
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Next i
End Sub
```